# Mapping XML into Entity Framework in c#

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, soap

I have about 25+ Classes with the data coming from SOAP WS and I need to store it into a SQL Server DB in C#.

At the moment I have created the classes with the entity framework and I go through the XML received manually and store it into the Entity Class manually and then call the db.SaveChanges().

As far as I've seen you use `xsd.exe` to create the classes and then map the string XML into them and then clone those classes to the Entities Classes and then save them. Is that the way? There is not a way so I just could skip that "clone" process?

PS: I am new in C#

Thanks in advance